# Node module as Typescript source only without build

Tags: typescript, node-modules, yarnpkg

I have written a small utility function in Typescript that I use in other projects. Currently, I have two different ways to share this, both with pros and cons. I would like to know if there is a way that I can have the best things from each method.

1. Build my TS code into a CJS/ESM module in a directory like `dist` and check it into the repo each time I make a change. Install it in my projects with `yarn install https://github.com/me/my-util`
2. Keep only TS source files in my utility repo, add it to each project as a submodule. When I build the project the files from this repo are built along with it as if they are part of the project.

If I `yarn install` a repo that has only TS source files. Is there a way I can configure my project to import those files without expecting them to be already compiled to JS? I understand that if someone tried to `yarn install` my utility in a 'normal' project it would not work but that's ok for this use case.

Bonus points if this could be done under [Yarn PnP](https://yarnpkg.com/features/pnp) where there is no `node_modules` folder.